# Need help creating a very simple script for my iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, notificationcenter

I know just enough about programming to know that what I'm asking for should be possible, but I have no idea how to make it happen. Hopefully someone here can help me out :)

My iPhone is jailbroken and working great. Just 1 problem. My Notification Center resets to defaults after a respring. I've tried various fixes that the general jailbreak community suggested, but nothing works. I have to go into the Notification Center settings and set it back up to my liking, and then it works perfectly until the next time I respring, and it all goes back to defaults again. And if you've ever had a jailbroken iPhone then you know that between installing tweaks and themes and all that, resprings are common.

Basically my idea was to have a script that runs automatically after a respring to configure the Notification Center back to how I like it. It would just automate the process of flipping a few toggles and reordering the apps that show up in the NC. In my mind this doesn't sound too complicated, just some boolean type stuff, but again, with my very limited knowledge of programming, I could be oblivious to what all would go into something like this.

So what do you guys think, would this be possible? Hopefully not too difficult? If you want to know the settings I would like to change I can provide that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notification Center stores it's settings in `/var/mobile/Library/BulletinBoard`.
You probably will be interested in files `SectionInfo.plist` and `SectionOrder.plist`
At first, try checking their permissions, it can be a possible cause of them not being saved. It should be `-rw-r--r-- mobile:mobile`.
You can make backup of this files and restore them when your NC gets messed up again, or write a script and run it from terminal, something like

```
cp /var/mobile/Library/BulletinBoard/SectionInfo.plist_backup /var/mobile/Library/BulletinBoard/SectionInfo.plist
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've already played around with those files. That's what the "normal" fix is, but my problem is different. It's like my NC doesn't see the SectionInfo.plist file at all. Normally if you delete or backup that file and respring, a new one is created and that fixes the issues. For me, that file is not recreated. I even got a copy of the file from someone else's phone that was working fine and put it in place, but no luck. That's why I came up with the script idea to automate manually setting the NC back up. If you have any idea why my SectionInfo.plist is broken, that would be great

Comment: Try checking permissions on /var/mobile/Library/BulletinBoard folder, should be drwxr-xr-x mobile:mobile. Also watch what system log writes on respring, maybe you will find some hints. Upload it on pastebin and post link here.

Comment: Holy crap, you're a genius! Somehow the permissions on the BulletinBoard folder were incorrect. I set it to what you said and now it works! I set up the NC how I want and respring and it stays that way! This is so awesome, thank you so much! You have no idea how annoying that problem was. It made me not want to install things from Cydia because then I'd have to fix it again. Thanks again!